# Fully resetting MySQL

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I've just spun up a CentOS 6 server. I installed mysql on it

```
yum install mysql-server
```

And after I started the MySQL service it spat out on STDOUT a bunch of stuff about the necessity of changing the password on my root account. I ran

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

and followed the prompts.

I then realised that the version of MySQL offered by CentOS' repository is wildly out of date, so I uninstalled it

```
service mysqld stop
yum remove mysql-*
```

I grabbed the latest MySQL Community Server RPM from Oracle's site and used

```
yum localinstall mysql-community-server-5.7.10-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server
```

But when I started it I didn't get any STDOUT messages about setting a password for my root user and when I ran mysql_secure_installation again it wouldn't accept my details, either with a blank password or with the password I'd set previously:

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried uninstalling mysql-community-server, manually deleting /var/lib/mysql, manually deleting /usr/share/mysql and then reinstalling mysql-server, the original package I installed, but I'm still not able to log back in to MySQL.

I also tried using

```
mysql_safe --init-file=/home/resetPassword.sql
```

with a file that contained commands to reset my root user's account and even try to make a new root user account, but this just crashed my SSH session and didn't reset my password.

I'm logged in as root so my omission of sudo shouldn't matter.

I don't have any data in the database that I need to preserve, I'd just like to be able to delete it completely and start from scratch.

Thanks,

YM

Answer (score 0):

Okay, managed to solve this one although I'm not entirely sure how.

Things I learned:

- Make sure all dependencies are the latest version, don't run something at 5.7.x and something else at 5.5.x
- Using sudo for yum **is** actually important even when logged in as root, as otherwise file permissions don't seem to be correctly set up
- Deleting the contents of /var/lib/mysql and running `sudo mysqld --initialize` resets everything
- When a MySQL server is reinitialised, it randomly generates a temporary password for the root user, which is saved to a log file. I'm not sure why the first time I installed it the password was not set, perhaps it's because I was using an older version of MySQL Server
- Deleting `/usr/share/mysql` is a bad idea, as the errmsg.sys file found in there is hard to reinstall for some reason.
- When trying to reset your root password using --init-file, make sure the password you are setting it to meets the current password policy requirements.

Hopefully something in that list helps someone else.